# MySQL query with multiple INNER JOIN is too slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
$sql="SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.*,t4.*,t5.*,t6.*,t7.*,t8.*,t9.asciiname as asciiname_9, t10.asciiname as asciiname_10,t11.*,t12.*
        FROM anunturi t1 
             INNER JOIN tip_proprietate t2 
                   ON t1.tip = t2.id_prop
             INNER JOIN anunt_preturi t3 
                   ON t1.id_anunt = t3.ext
             INNER JOIN anunturi_images t5 
                   ON t1.id_anunt = t5.id_ext 
             INNER JOIN tranzactie t4 
                   ON t1.tranzactie = t4.id_tranzactie
             INNER JOIN anunt_descriere t6 
                   ON t1.id_anunt = t6.ext
             INNER JOIN anunt_locatie t7 
                   ON t1.id_anunt = t7.ext
             INNER JOIN zone t8 
                   ON t7.zona = t8.id_zona
             INNER JOIN locatii t9 
                   ON t7.judet = t9.admin1_code 
                   AND t9.feature_code='ADM1'
             INNER JOIN locatii t10 
                   ON t7.oras = t10.geonameid
             INNER JOIN anunt_suprafete t11 
                   ON t1.id_anunt = t11.ext
             INNER JOIN tip_locuinta t12 
                   ON t1.tip2 = t12.id_loc
    GROUP BY t1.id_anunt 
       WHERE t1.status=0
    ORDER BY t1.id_anunt DESC 
       LIMIT 3";
```

and I use `SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1` before the query. It runs very slow.

Comment: Do you have indexes on the columns you do join's with? do you really need all the columns from all the tables? How long it takes?

Comment: Indices,tables,explain,the kitchen sink.

Comment: I have indexes the columns and I need all the columns.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html - you need to use this.  You have not given anywhere near enough data for anyone else here to do much more than take a wild guess.

Comment: Please run `EXPLAIN` on the query, so put explain before the select and post the result here.

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` on just one column while selecting many columns of which none have a `MIN`,`MAX`,`SUM` etc. is suspicious. Do you need the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: I think there is not enough comments, mentioning the `EXPLAIN`. OP, post `EXPLAIN`!

Comment: Yeah I need Group By because I need only 1 image(t5) for each result

Answer (score 1):

Aside from trying to pull every column from almost every table, and you state
you already have indexes, I would try ensuring the following covering indexes

```
table          index
locatii        ( feature_code, admin1_code, asciiname )
locatii        ( geonameid, asciiname )  <-- for use when join via T10
anunt_locatie  ( judet, zona, oras, ext )
anunturi       ( id_anunt, status )
```

Then, I would restructure the query to put the t9 alias first if that table 
would be expected to have a smaller set of records returned vs the t1 alias
based on status of zero... and add keyword "STRAIGHT_JOIN"

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      t1.*, 
      t2.*, 
      t3.*,
      t4.*,
      t5.*,
      t6.*,
      t7.*,
      t8.*,
      t9.asciiname as asciiname_9, 
      t10.asciiname as asciiname_10,
      t11.*,
      t12.*
   FROM 
      locatii t9 
         INNER JOIN anunt_locatie t7 
            ON t9.admin1_code = t7.judet

            INNER JOIN zone t8 
               ON t7.zona = t8.id_zona

            INNER JOIN locatii t10 
               ON t7.oras = t10.geonameid

            INNER JOIN anunturi t1 
               ON t7.ext = t1.id_anunt
              AND t1.status = 0   
               INNER JOIN tip_proprietate t2 
                  ON t1.tip = t2.id_prop
               INNER JOIN anunt_preturi t3 
                  ON t1.id_anunt = t3.ext
               INNER JOIN tranzactie t4 
                  ON t1.tranzactie = t4.id_tranzactie
               INNER JOIN anunturi_images t5 
                  ON t1.id_anunt = t5.id_ext 
               INNER JOIN anunt_descriere t6 
                  ON t1.id_anunt = t6.ext
               INNER JOIN anunt_suprafete t11 
                  ON t1.id_anunt = t11.ext
               INNER JOIN tip_locuinta t12 
                  ON t1.tip2 = t12.id_loc
   GROUP BY 
      t1.id_anunt 
   WHERE
      t9.feature_code='ADM1'
   ORDER BY 
      t1.id_anunt DESC 
   LIMIT 3
```